# Android loop ListView

Tags: android, json, listview, onclick

So I'm making a quiz for android and I have a problem. I parse the questions and answers from a server in JSONArrays and get what I want. So when I start the activity the first question with its associated answers are displayed, the question in a TextView and the answers in a ListView. But here's the problem, I want to see the next question when I select an answer, so I want to loop through the JSONObject and display a new question when the previous has been answered. Anyone have any idea how I can do that?

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.game);
    listView = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.list_answers);
    gametv = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.text_question);

    Intent intent = getIntent();

    final String gameID = intent.getStringExtra("gameID");
    final int questionAmount = intent.getIntExtra("amount", 0);
    final Set<String> set = new HashSet<String>();


    JSONArray quiz = null;
    try {
        JSONObject json = new JSONObject();
        json.put("gameID", gameID);

        quiz = SendHttp.parseHttp(qURL, "result", json);



            displayQuiz(quiz, questionAmount);


    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }


    listView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
            int position, long id) {

            TextView tv = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.tv_1);
            String answerString = tv.getText().toString();

            set.add(answerString);
            Toast.makeText(Game.this, answerString, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            Log.w("svarat", set.toString());

        }
    });
}

private void displayQuiz(JSONArray jsona, int amount) throws JSONException {



    gametv.setText(jsona.getJSONObject(0).getString("question"));

    int numberOfAnswers = Integer.parseInt(jsona.getJSONObject(0).getString("n"));

    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> mylist = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
    HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();

    for (int i = 0; i < numberOfAnswers; i++) {


        String qans = jsona.getJSONObject(0).getString(String.valueOf(i+1));

        JSONObject answer = new JSONObject(qans);

        map.put("answerID", answer.getString("answerID"));
        map.put("answer", answer.getString("answer"));


        mylist.add(map);

        map = new HashMap<String, String>();


    }
    SimpleAdapter sadapter = new SimpleAdapter(this, mylist, R.layout.quizlist, new String[] {"answerID","answer"},
            new int[] {R.id.tv_1, R.id.tv_2}); 


    listView.setAdapter(sadapter);

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried calling [notifyDataSetChanged()](http://developer.android.com/intl/fr/reference/android/widget/BaseAdapter.html#notifyDataSetChanged%28%29) on your listView?

**ADDITION**

So if everything displays properly for the first question, here is an approach to increment on each answer click.

```
int questionNumber = 0;
...

    ...
    listView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
            int position, long id) {
            questionNumber++;
            ...

            displayQuiz(...);
        }
    }

    private void displayQuiz(JSONArray jsona, int amount) throws JSONException {
        gametv.setText(jsona.getJSONObject(questionNumber).getString("question"));
        ...
    }
    ...
```

Comment: No I haven't, great tip. But how will I use it to loop trough the JSONArray?

Comment: I see, your question is getting the data _out_ of a JSONArray not putting it _in_ the ListView. **My apologies.** And I haven't worked with JSON so I am useless here.

Comment: `String qans = jsona.getJSONObject(0).getString(String.valueOf(i+1));` It not as simple as calling `getJSONObject(1)` for the next question is it?

Comment: Nonono, I get it as I want. As I said, the first question and its answers are displayed from JSONObject(0) but I want to loop through it like JSONObject(i) and when I click an item in the ListView I want i to increase and the next question to show. So it's the loop I can't figure out how to make.

Comment: qans is just for getting the 4 answers to the question. But I want the next question when I click on a ListItem, that's my problem.

Comment: Rewrite a distinction between `buildQuiz()` and `showQuiz()`. Call `buildQuiz()` once from `onCreate` or `onResume`; this is where you define SimpleAdapter etc. And call `showQuiz()` from your ListView's `onItemClickListener`. I don't believe you need to create a new adapter every time you rewrite your question and answers.

Comment: Okey I'll try it out and I'll get back with the result later! Thank you very much!

Comment: Well, why not go back to your original displayQuiz() with the change `getJSONObject(questionNumber)`? After you have finished your entire app, then you can analyze if it needs to be more efficient or if it is perfect already.

Comment: You're welcome, please check my answer to let everyone know this is solved.